# Assembly locations for Visuals Studio Toolbox

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005, compact-framework

I'm trying to setup my development envrionment on a Windows 7 64-bit edition system. I've installed VS2005 and VS2008 alright.

At work, we have several self-developed control libraries for the .NET Compact Framework. Under Windows XP 32-bit I was able to store them in a folder C:\owncontrols and add the folder to

```
[HKLM\...\Microsoft\.NETCompactFramework\VERSION\WindowsCE\AssemblyFoldersEx\COMPANYNAME]
```

The folder structure is as follows:

```
c:\owncontrols\libname\2.0\dllname.dll
c:\owncontrols\libname\2.0\dllname.wm5.dll
c:\owncontrols\libname\3.5\dllname.dll
c:\owncontrols\libname\3.5\dllname.wm5.dll
```

The DLLs all have the same version number. After putting the entries into the registry, I was able to add the controls to the toolbox and Visual Studio would choose the correct DLL depending on the framework version and the type of device (WM5 or WinCE 5).

Under Windows 7 I'm not able to do this, somehow. I found the registry entries under `WOW6432Node` node in `HLKM\Software` and made the entries just the same as under XP, but  the controls don't show up in Visual Studio when I'm trying to add them to the toolbox.

So maybe I'm doing it all wrong? How would I add the controls as described for XP? Please note that installing to the GAC is not an option here - these libraries change frequently.

I really liked the feature that Visual Studio selected the right DLL depending on framework version and project type. I tried adding the DLLs manually, but then I see all the controls doubled.

Thanks for any help
Thorsten

Comment: Have you tried just dragging and dropping the control assemblies onto the toolbox?

Comment: Actually I haven't tried this. However, I don't want to lose the feature that VS picks the right assembly for the target platform and .NET version. I'd have to drop 4 assemblies onto the toolbox, two of them having the same name (see folder structur above).

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this tutorial article:

[Visual Studio Toolbox Control Integration](http://www.componentowl.com/articles/visual-studio-toolbox-control-integration)

It would most probably have something to do with the bitness of your OS.

Have you tried AssemblyFolders as well (not only AssemblyFoldersEx)?

```
32-bit OS: HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\AssemblyFolders\<your control name>
64-bit OS: HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\AssemblyFolders\<your control name>

32-bit OS: HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319\AssemblyFoldersEx\<your control name>
64-bit OS: HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319\AssemblyFoldersEx\<your control name>
```

In both cases, the default value for the key is a string with full path to the folder with your assembly.